# Where do I find the short chain names for Gnosis Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

The Gnosis front-end embeds some short chain name in the url, like rin for rinkeby in the below example:
https://gnosis-safe.io/app/rin:0xBa5820358863D215dBCb2f030Ff1c46a7200a559/balances

Where can I find a list of these short chain names such as rin, eth, bsc? I need to know the ones for arbitrum.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix is also known as the `shortName`. A curated list can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains).

The `shortName` for [Arbitrum One](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains/blob/master/_data/chains/eip155-42161.json) (currently supported by the Safe) is `arb1`.